# Trying to mount Samsung T5 SSD on Manajaro

Tags: mount, ssd

I just received my Samsung T5 SSD. It is not mounted automatically, unfortunately. I tried a lot of things on my own to mount it manually, but I don't know how. I even don't know if it is actually possible and supported.

The device is not listed in gparted tool.

Anyone can help me with this? `lsubs` does list the device. `fdisk -l` does not.

```
aq@aq ~> lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 04e8:61f5 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Portable SSD T5
...
```

```
aq@aq ~> sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476,94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: PC401 NVMe SK hynix 512GB               
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 929F45FA-8E2B-4F2E-AE03-A6A2A46D723A

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      4097     618497    614401   300M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    618498  964396811 963778314 459,6G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 964396812 1000206899  35810088  17,1G Linux swap
```

```
aq@aq ~> sudo lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 459,6G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  17,1G  0 part [SWAP]
```

**How can I use/mount this device?**

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204208/samsung-ssd-t5-compatibily-with-ubuntu) "Samsung T3, T5 and T7 SSDs are **not** compatible with Linux, if encrypted". From [the manual](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi.static/Samsung_Portable_SSD_T5_User_Manual_English_1.2.pdf): "Because T5 utilizes advanced encryption technologies, user data cannot be accessed if you forgot your password."

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341088/how-access-files-on-portable-ssd-samsung-t5-on-ubuntu-20-04) it exposes a builtin CDROM like partition with the software which could be used to unlock it.

Please try unlocking/unencrypting them under Windows/MacOS first.

There's a [Java utility](https://github.com/rsenden/t3unlock) which unlocks the Samsung T3 SSD which works under Linux but I'm not sure it's applicable to other drives.

Comment: I am not sure if that is the case. The second link is a copy (of contents) of the first one. This is just one source which is also outdated. I could not find more sources claiming this.

Comment: How is it outdated exactly? The drive is locked and encrypted.